# How to delete a Json object from Json File by sed command in BASH

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I a have a JSON file in which a JSON object needs to be deleted.
Is there any way to delete it by using the sed command only?
My sample file is given below.

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "description": "XYZ",
  "versions": {},
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "default_attributes": {},
  "override_attributes": {
    "company": {
      "xyz": {
        "mailer": {
          "smtp_host": "Some IP",
          "imap_host": "Some Host",
          "imap_user": "Some UserId",
          "reply_to": "Some User Id",
          "outbound_user": "",
          "imap_mail_domain": "compute.oraclecloud.com",
          "imap_password": ""
        },
        "logicaldomainname": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to delete the mailer object from the file using the sed command.
Please take a look and let me know if it is possible using the sed command.

My main motive of this deletion is to replace this object with new
mailer object so that the next time when another mailer object will be posted then we will append it in xyz JSON object.

Expected output:

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "description": "",
  "version": {},
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "default_attributes": {},
  "override_attributes": {
    "Company": {
      "XYZ": {
        "logicaldomainname": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: actually jq we can not use due to some licensing regulations in our machines. but we can use awk,

Comment: `sed` is definitely not appropriate. If `jq` is not an option, you should consider using Perl or Python: they have great json libraries.

Comment: added the expected output..

Answer (score 10):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/\"mailer\"/,/}/ d; /^$/d' 1.a
```

"Delete from `mailer` to the first `}`, then delete all blank lines (you input has one)".

To overwrite the file ("in-place")

```
sed -i ...
```

*Note: works for multiline files (as yours).*

Comment: And if someone's user id is `mailer`?

Comment: What if 'mailer' has a nested JSON object in it?

Comment: This works perfectly for deleting the 'devDependencies' section of a package.json file! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You should strongly consider resolving the licensing issue that prohibits `jq`:

```
jq 'del(.override_attributes.company.xyz.mailer) | .description=""' input.json
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{sub(/"mailer":[^}]+},[[:space:]]+/,"")}1' file
{
        "name": "ABC",
        "description": "",
        "versions": {

        },
        "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
        "chef_type": "environment",
        "default_attributes": {

        },
        "override_attributes": {
          "Company": {
            "XYZ": {
                    "logicaldomainname": ""
                      }
                      }
        }
    }
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS, with other awks you'd build up the record one line at a time and handle it in the END section:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{rec=rec $0 RS} END{sub(/"mailer":[^}]+},[[:space:]]+/,"",rec); print rec}' file
{
        "name": "ABC",
        "description": "",
        "versions": {

        },
        "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
        "chef_type": "environment",
        "default_attributes": {

        },
        "override_attributes": {
          "Company": {
            "XYZ": {
                    "logicaldomainname": ""
                      }
                      }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @ED Morton, the first one is working fine for me.

Comment: second answers seems that it is printing the expected result but in orginal file it is not changing while the first answer is doing the same..

Comment: both scripts have identical behavior and neither are intended to modify the original file. GNU awk has a `-i inplace` option to do that (`awk -i inplace '...script...' file`) but in general with any UNIX command `cmd` to modify the original file you'd do: `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: "And if someone's user id is `mailer`?" It will delete from it to the first `},...here more spaces...`, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but if you're asking what if something on the right side of a `:` matched the string `"mailer"` - that can't happen as I'm including the `:` after the string in the regexp (`sub(/"mailer":`). If that's not the question, please clarify.